# Return value of RESTful Web Service, taking a null value into account

Tags: java, rest, unmarshalling

I am creating a client to my RESTful Web Service. 
In this case, my Server will not always return the expected object (e.g. nothing found on a given parameter, so return is NULL).

```
@GET
@Path("/person/{name}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return people.byName(name);
}
```

The byName() method will return NULL if the given name is not found. Upon unmarshalling the given object, this will raise an exception. What is the most common and clean way to just result in an if/else statement or something to handle the returns in different ways?

```
JAXBContext jcUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jcUnmarshaller.createUnmarshaller();
return (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(connection.getInputStream());
```

**SOLUTION**

```
getPerson( ) throws WebApplicationException { 
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
}
```

Comment: "throws WebApplicationException" signature is useless since WebApplicationException is a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way to handle such situations is to return 404 Not Found response code. With [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) you can throw [`WebApplicationException`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html#WebApplicationException(int)):

```
@GET
@Path("/person/{name}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    Person personOrNull = people.byName(name);
    if(personOrNull == null) {
      throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }   
    return personOrNull;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and my JBoss server logs are now littered with exceptions. Makes real error tracing tricky.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee: Use NoLogWebApplicationException instead of WebApplicationException to keep the exception out of your logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a pure REST service, you should return the HTTP response code 404 - Not Found when a person isn't found. So, it would look something like this:

```
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    Person person = people.byName(name);
    if (null != person) {
       return person
    }
    else {
       //return 404 response code (not sure how to do that with what you're using)
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer on how to return 404 in [tag:jax-rs]. However +1, you were first.